# Hold or hot humidifier for best effect

Tags: humidity

I'm creating my own humidifier, but I'm not really sure if I should create a room temperature humidifier or a hot/cold humidifier. 
If I go for the cold/hot option, I'll be using a peltier element, so I can just swap it around if I want to get hot or cold water. I'm not sure if the added cost/effort of the peltier will compensate.
The peltier will dump the heat/cold into the same room that the device is humidiating

Comment: Is this about the cost of the peltier element, what size? How efficient? Or just what type?

Comment: @SolarMike both! The peltier will dump it's thermal opposite side into the same room as the I'm trying to humidify

Comment: I asked 4 questions... so “both” is a poor answer.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry! I'm not sure what peltier module I'll be using. If I need to cool it or heat it, I need a module that is sufficient to heat/cool around 12L of water. I'm tempted to put the peltier next to the evaporator to only cool/heat around the evaporator.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to spend a lot on an electronic heat / cooling source. , have you considered ultrasonic methods of vaporizing the water?  Ultrasonic uses sound we cannot hear 67khz if memory serves some fog machines use this method. I have also seen high pressure used with tiny orifices but this is usually for large buildings and requires more maintenance.

Comment: You say to just skip the heating/cooling functionality? There is one other method that involves a filter that sucks up the water in combination with a fan that pulls air through that filter. The water will then stick to the air, which will humidify the air.